# Seemingly random PostgreSQL connection drops while handling Django requests

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, gunicorn, psycopg2

For the past few days, our Django website has been experiencing random PostgreSQL connection drops that would raise `InterfaceError: connection already closed` in random locations. The queries that cause the error occur in different views at random and we can't replicate the issue reliably. It occurs very frequently, somewhere between 1-10% of requests that make DB queries.

All stack traces follow the same pattern. The only thing that differs is the location of our query that caused it. Here is an example stack trace.

```
InterfaceError: connection already closed
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 301, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()

InterfaceError: connection already closed
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "contextlib.py", line 79, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/views/generic/base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "tolink/views/app.py", line 273, in get
    self.set_profile(pk)
  File "tolink/views/app.py", line 267, in set_profile
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(pk=pk, user=self.request.user).first()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 1047, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by("pk"))[:1]:
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 394, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 300, in _cursor
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 301, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Details of our setup:

- Django 4.1.7
- gunicorn 20.1.0
- psycopg2 2.9.5
- PostgreSQL 14.6
- Heroku basic dyno (hosting the django server)
- Basic Heroku Postgres (hosting PostgreSQL)

The portion of `settings.py` that's relevant to the DB looks like this:

```
CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS = True
CONN_MAX_AGE = None

DATABASES = {
    "default": dj_database_url.config(
        conn_max_age=CONN_MAX_AGE,
        conn_health_checks=True,
        ssl_require=env("DATABASE_SSL_REQUIRED"),
    )
}

DATABASES["default"]["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] = True
```

I found some old stack overflow and Django forum questions that seemed to experience similar problems, however, their solutions were specific to their stack (nginx + uwsgi). Unlike in other questions, PostgreSQL connection limit seems to not be the problem in this case (2 worker threads only with a limit of 20 connections). These problems occur in production, not during testing or local development.

I tried updating the dependencies, restarting the database/server, and played around with database settings.

Comment: How does the server experience this problem (look in the server log file)

Comment: If you mean the gunicorn+django log, then it's just the path information + the stack trace. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the PostgreSQL logs, however, it seems like the issue is on the client-side.

Comment: My guess it is to do with `django/utils/asyncio.py`. I see `asyncio` and expect trouble, especially given all the if, and or buts here {Async](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/).

Comment: That's really weird as async is not enabled in my django projects and I'm not using any async libraries or code.

Comment: Hmm, then you will need to look at the Postgres logs and see what is happening before the error is thrown.

Comment: I meant the PostgreSQL log file.  If the problem is exclusively client-side (the pool get confused about what connections are open and closed), there might be nothing interesting in that log file, but it would be nice to confirm that.  Even better if log_connections and log_disconnections were turned on.  You might need to make friends with whomever does have access to the log file.  Life is hard without suitable friends.

Comment: See `db/__init__.py` for `close_old_connections`. The name is a bit misleading since it will also close connections severed by the Postgres server, not just "old" connections. Django registers this function to run on both request start and request finished. If you have any code that accesses the ORM before request start then the error may occur.